# angular6 how to create an injected service by string name

Tags: angular, angular6

for example, I had injected three service: AService, BService, CService in root module. and in a component, there is a string variable named 'type', now I hope to dynamic call an injected service by the 'type'. such as: if type === 'A', then should inject AService, and call aService.xxx(); if type === 'B', then should inject BService, and call bService.xxx();

added: my purpose is that when adding a new service like DService, I can dynamic call it by the type value, and don't have to change any code in this component.

Answer (score 1):

Inject Angular's `Injector` into your component.
Publish your services in your `app.module.ts`'s `providers` section using an `InjectionToken`

```
{ provide: new InjectionToken<string>('A'), useClass: AService }
```

and then get it in your component by calling

```
let type = 'A'; // ...
const service = this.injector.get(new InjectionToken<string>(type)) as XxxService;
service.xxx();
```

where `XxxService` is an interface declaring the method `xxx()`.

You may also directly use strings instead of wrapping them in `InjectionToken`s but this is deprecated.

- https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection
- https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action

Comment: If you are in a multi-module project it is necessary to use the same injection token, export a const and use that across where it is needed. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53317225/angular-injectiontoken-throws-no-provider-for-injectiontoken