# Angular InjectionToken throws 'No provider for InjectionToken'

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm currently learning the new Angular framework, and I'm trying to make a dynamic search bar which accepts a service name as an argument in order for it to dynamically resolve a service to query the backend service with.

For this I'm using an `Injector`, and loading the the service during `ngOnInit`. This works fine when using a string based provider, however my IDE notes that it's deprecated and I should use an `InjectionToken` which I can't seem to wrap my head around.

I expected the following code to work, as removing all instances of `InjectionToken` and replacing them with the direct string literal works:

I tried looking at the following documentation, but I didn't quite understand it as I feel like I did exactly what it says, yet it keeps telling me it doesn't work: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

**Module declaration**

```
// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SearchBarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: new InjectionToken<ISearchable>('CustomerService'), // <-- doesn't work;  'CustomerService' <-- works
      useValue: CustomerService
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Search bar component:**

```
// search-bar.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.sass']
})
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  source: string;

  private searcher: ISearchable;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // error: Error: No provider for InjectionToken CustomerService!
    let token = new InjectionToken<ISearchable>(this.source);
    this.searcher = this.injector.get<ISearchable>(token);

    // this works, but it's deprecated and will probably break in the future
    // this.searcher = this.injector.get(this.source);
    console.log(this.searcher);
  }
}
```

**Using the search bar:**

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<div class="row justify-content-center mb-2">
  <div class="col-8">
    <search-bar title="Customers" source="CustomerService"></search-bar>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Edit: Here's an example with the error:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3admbe

Comment: It's not `provide, useValue` but `provide, useClass` : values are for instanciated values, and you're giving it a class, not an instance of your class.

Comment: @trichetriche thanks for the tip :) but the issue sadly persists

Comment: Could you make a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.com ? That would help in resolving the issue

Comment: And also, could you test this : `{
      useValue: new InjectionToken<ISearchable>('CustomerService'), 
      provide: CustomerService
    }` (the opposite of what you have written)

Comment: @trichetriche added the example link

Comment: (Usually you provide the edit link to see the code, but since I know how to get it, I'll go ahed and let you edit your link)

Comment: @trichetriche made it editable

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After asking on the official angular repository, it turns out to be a simple solution. Instead of passing the service name as a string, you'll have pass the tokens through the component into the view into another component.

### Globally define the injection token

I did this alongside my service itself to make it easier to keep track of.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomerService implements ISearchable { ... }

export const CUSTOMER_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<ISearchable>('CustomerService');
```

### Register the injection token in your app providers

```
import {CUSTOMER_SERVICE, CustomerService} from "./services/customer/customer.service";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ... ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: CUSTOMER_SERVICE,  // That's the token we defined previously
      useClass: CustomerService,  // That's the actual service itself
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ ... ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### Pass the token through the view to your other component

```
// In your component
import {CUSTOMER_SERVICE} from "./services/customer/customer.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<app-search-bar [source]="searcher"></app-search-bar>'
})
export class AppComponent
{
  searcher = CUSTOMER_SERVICE;
}
```

### You can now import the service dynamically from your other component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.sass'],
})
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit
{
  @Input()
  source: InjectionToken<ISearchable>;

  private searcher: ISearchable;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.searcher = this.injector.get<ISearchable>(this.source);
  }

  search(query: string)
  {
    this.searcher.search(query).subscribe(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: This creates a dependency and if you are in 2 separate modules, you really need them completely independent. So passing the original token, would not really fix the issue. .get('TOKEN_NAME'), should not really be deprecated it this is going to be the solution now. I hope angular team realize that.

Comment: @MohyEldeen exactly my thoughts. Their current setup isn't modular in the slightest

Comment: I just built an example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-injection-token-test?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodule2%2Fservice-provider.service.ts
I will open a ticket that they should not remove .get('name'), without fixing this.

Comment: If it make sense, please vote for the git issue I created, because they closed it and I am hoping it will re-open https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28136

Answer (score 8):

For anyone still struggling with this, it may be as simple as restarting VS Code, as was the case for me.  I'm not sure why, but that fixed it for me.  Of course, I tried this first, because I was quite certain the error was wrong to begin with.

Comment: This is actually not a bad answer - I've hit this numerous times. Sometimes the Angular compiler doesn't pick up changes in modules in serve mode and you need to restart the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Something you can do us instead of implementing the service into the AppModule's providers' list, you could just add providedIn to root parameter to service's injectable annotation.

https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-a-service

Example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
}
```

But, there is one more method, your method. Services can be used into the module's providers' list without requiring any IncpetionToken, because are already incpected, so you can just add it to providers list.

https://angular.io/guide/providers#provider-scope

Example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SearchBarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    CustomerService // <-- You don't need to create any token.
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: How would I use this inside my component?

Comment: Using `{
  providedIn: 'root',
}` declares a singleton, which isn't what the OP seems to need.

Comment: Yes but I want to use it inside a component without having to hard-code it, meaning any `ISearchable` service should be able to be fetched from the dependency injector, like a simple key-value lookup which doesn't seem to work with `InjectionToken`s but works fine if I pass a string (which is somehow deprecated)

Comment: @Paradoxis check the changes I have done: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ek7qf6

Comment: @NikolaosGrammatikos that, yet again, just moves the problem, I don't want my service to be hard-coded in my any of my components, it has to be simply queried via a string in my tag (see 'hello.component.ts' and 'search-bar.component.ts')

Comment: @Paradoxis https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken#tree-shakable-injectiontoken ???

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing it all up.

Tokens are made to be plain objects. By using a service with a dependency injection, you can't declare it as a token.

To create services on demand, you will have to use a factory. A factory is a function that will create instances of your class, with given properties.

In my example, I have added the endpoint as the given propety, but you can do whatever you want in your factory.

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dg1hut?file=src/app/search-bar/search-bar.component.ts

```js
const factory = (http: HttpClient) => new CustomerService(http, '/api/v1/customer')
// ...
providers: [{
  provide: CustomerService,
  useFactory: factory,
  deps: [HttpClient]
}],
```

```js
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() source: string;
  constructor(private searcher: CustomerService) { }
  ngOnInit() { console.log(this.searcher); }
  search() { return this.searcher.search(''); }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem though, I want to *dynamically resolve a service to query the backend service with* (like you could do in AngularJS with `$injector.get('MyServiceName');`), this simply hard-codes the service in the constructor which is exactly what I don't want as the component no longer is modular

Comment: The service is hard-coded but it's value isn't : it depends on the factory. This means you can create several factories, each returning a custom instance of the service, with different properties. And the injector is only there to fetch you a dependency injected into your module, both in Angular and AngularJS : it's not there to dynamically resolve a service. If you wish to keep your token, you will have to declare it as a service configuration, not as a whole service, because as said, tokens aren't made to be class instances with dependencies but only plain objects.

Comment: I get that, but I simply want to do a simple key-value lookup in wherever my services are defined, that's it; the commented out examples work but they're deprecated and I simply can't seem to port them to Angular's new format

Comment: And again, it works because it's very simple; it just fetches your service. That's not different from using the constructor to inject a dependency. If you want to override a property in your service, you will have to use a factory or a token. If you want to override your whole service, you will have to use a factory or a provider override. What you do now is using a token to override your whole service. It won't work, no matter how hard you try. If your need is to override your whole service, you simply can't use an injection token.

Answer (score 1):

for Angular 15 with standalone components in 2023 we should define injection tokens in routes, for my situation with mfe and libs in case when it needs to have injection token we need to put them to `entryRoutes.ts` array

```
export const remoteRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RemoteEntryComponent,
    children: uiRoutesChildren,
    providers: [
      {
        provide: 'API_URL',
        useValue: API_URL,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

source: https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components